# How Many Hours of Game Playing can Iphone 4 Support?

Tags: iphone, battery

[iPhone 4 supports](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html):

1. up to 6 hours of 3G
2. up to 10 hours of wifi

But how many hours of game play can iphone 4 support?

I've been playing Angry Birds recently and it seems to me that the iPhone can only support **5** hours of Angry Birds. Is this normal?

Comment: Do you keep WiFi/Bluetooth on while playing?

Comment: It depends on how awesome the game is.

Comment: to maximize on time, i would turn on airplane mode, which turns off the radios, etc..

Comment: @Jawa, no WIFI/Bluetooth

Comment: @mipadi, do you think Angry Birds is awesome enough to warrant such a short battery time?

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: I've never played it, actually.

Comment: I depends how intense the game is. 3D games (Modern Warfare 2) take alot more power than angry birds does (2D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing games on your iPhone uses a lot more processing power than 3G or wifi.  The higher the cpu usage, the faster the battery drains.  I'm actually surprised you get as much battery life as you do, that seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using a high resolution game that requires a lot of computing power (like R Racing or Infinity Blade) in 3 or 4 hours the battery should be completely drained, 5 hours it's a lot...